# Unable to add SSSnackbar to view tied to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using SSSnackbar for iOS: https://github.com/stonesam92/SSSnackbar and I am following their example exactly. Problem is, it works on some view controllers that I have and do not work on others.

Specifically, in one viewcontroller which has its view defined completely by its corresponding XIB file, when I try to show the Snackbar, it says:

**Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview**

Which refers to this line in the source code:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-6-[self]-(6)-|"
```

In this particular viewcontroller I don't call self.view or addSubview at all, since it is completely defined by an XIB file tied to it. My question is, how do I get the snackbar to work correctly with that?

Answer (score 0):

Wow I'm an idiot, its because I need to call it in ViewDidAppear.....hope this helps someone else out.